# How is Cross Site Flashing performed?

Tags: web-application, attacks, xss, flash

I read about cross site flashing in the OWASP testing guide. I know the difference between XSS and XSF. But what I am looking for is how attackers perform a XSF attack. How is it possible since there are no entry points for a flash file?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

> Cross-Site Flashing occurs when user controlled data is not validated
>   and used in one of the following functions or variables:
>
> ```
> loadVariables
> loadMovie
> getURL
> loadMovie
> loadMovieNum
> FScrollPane.loadScrollContent
> Sound.loadSound
> NetStream.play
> flash.external.ExternalInterface.call
> htmlText
> ```
>
> In other words, this means that the Flash application must reference
>   external URLs, and the locations of those URLs are set through user
>   defined parameters (usually Flash Vars).
>
> In order for this vulnerability to be successfully exploited the
>   victim needs to click on a specially crafted link created by the
>   attacker that will use the vulnerable Flash application in order to,
>   for example, steal users' credentials.

Even if Flash scripts have restrictions due to the same-origin policy (for Flash you can read its details on [here](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_Flash))  Flash is a vector for XSS attacks. 
For such vulnerabilities, you do not need necessarily entries for users as on this [demo](http://demo.testfire.net/vulnerable.swf) or as on this [website](http://www.sharedtalk.com/) that manages a huge database and entirely built in Flash Player.
You can find several real world examples of such XSF attacks on [here](http://cve.mitre.org/data/refs/refmap/source-IDEFENSE.html).
I think the simplest and best tutorial about XSF attacks is [this one](http://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/178.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I understand such things can be done with flash. But if a web application is using flash how can an attacker exploit it? That's what I am specifically searching for.

Comment: @AnanduMDas Do you mean classic attacks on Flash Player applications or just XSF ones ?

Comment: I know about the classical XSS attacks. I want to know about the flashing attacks only.

Comment: @AnanduMDas I reedited my answer. If you need something more just be precise :) Thanks